# How to reduce the amount of data transferred with Blazor server

Tags: data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor component that fetch data from a service and then render data into a table.

This is my scenario:

- The service returns a list of objects, each object contains a large set of properties and an object hierarchy
- The user interface must only display a small amount of this data, therefore only some `@myObject.MyProperty` properties are displayed

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private List<WeatherForecast> forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = ForecastService.List;
        ForecastService.MyEvent += _Event;
    }

    private void _Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

So in this case `WeatherForecast` is a large object, but only a small set of its properties are displayed.
Is this scenario already optimized by the Blazor or does the server always "serve" the entire object to the client?

Comment: Blazor Server only sends UI changes to the client, so if you ask to display one property it sends just what is required to display that one property

Comment: And if one property out of ten displayed changes - it only send the change for that one property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is effectively 'optimized' to send only the changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1#comparison-to-server-rendered-ui

From the Blazor docs (from Blazor Server section):

> A UI update in Blazor is triggered by:
>
> User interaction, such as selecting a button. App triggers, such as a
>   timer. The graph is rerendered, and a UI diff (difference) is
>   calculated. This diff is the smallest set of DOM edits required to
>   update the UI on the client. The diff is sent to the client in a
>   binary format and applied by the browser.